# Is building the project manually a good way

Tags: java, build

We are using MyEclipse IDE for all our Java needs. Till now our team did use the `Build Automatically` option in the Project menu of the IDE.

So MyEclipse IDE users how do you manage your build process? Also integrating Ant/Maven also a good idea?

I hope this is a suitable question for this site otherwise, mods please feel free to take the post down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every project ( no matter how big or small ) should begin with:

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

and then be imported into Eclipse.

This is the first thing you should type instinctively before starting a new Java project.

Waiting until almost the end of a project to integrate a environment agnostic build environment is missing the point entirely.

Comment: Not to mention all the hours of banging your head off the wall trying to mavenize a project so late in its development cycle.

Answer (score 5):

Integrating Maven is always a good idea. That way the build process isn't IDE-specific, and developers can work on the project in different IDEs.

I use NetBeans which has easy Maven integration. I know that Eclipse has a popular and well-maintained Maven plugin. Not familiar with MyEclipse, however...

As for learning Maven, I would recommend this free online text: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/index.html

Comment: I really hated learning maven. That being said, once I managed to get the hang of it I couldn't see myself developing without it. I highly suggest Maven for anyone developing Java apps, big or small.

Answer (score 0):

The Build-automatically option in eclipse is not the same thing as an ant or maven build system. If you `build automatically`, then eclipse will compile your code when you save the file, and it will show you errors in your code sooner. See [Purpose of the "Build Automatically" option in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677127/purpose-of-the-build-automatically-option-in-eclipse)

I always recommend doing the automatic build!

As for Maven/Ant. I am a big fan of Ant, and I have hated using Maven. Also, there are times when Maven's best features (the autiomatic dependency resolution) is more of a problem than a help.

I recommend that people understand the Java build process, and don't leave it to some parrot-fashion system that hides the most important infrastructure from you.