# Why does eclipse start building after a crash?

Tags: eclipse, versioning, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Why does eclipse start building  after a crash?
The big problem is that I'm working with ClearCase UCM plugin and building takes up to two hours.
What's the problem? Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: why don't you turn off auto-build? Menu is project->Build Automtically

Comment: as said in above comment uncheck your Build Automatically option in Project-> Build Automatically. It will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the build will take much more time in a dynamic view (network access) than in a snapshot one (local disk access).
See "[What are the differences between a snapshot view and a dynamic view?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309)".

Before disabling the "Build automatically" eclipse option, check if the issue persists in a snapshot view.
Anyway, an automatic build is generally active only in a continuous integration environment (as shown in [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/09/continuousintegrationrationalclearcaseremoteclient/)).

---

The OP reports the following solution:

> **Disable the build-before-launch**:
>
> - Select "`Window->Preferences`".
> - In the tree view pane, expand the "`Run/Debug`" node, and select "`Launching`".
> - Disable (uncheck) the "`Build (if required) before launching`" option in the "`General Options`" section, and then click "OK".

The [Launching Preferences for Juno](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/run-debug/ref-launching.htm) do mention that this option is "on" by default.

[image]

Comment: Build automatically is disabled for a very long time, but eclipse is still doing that build after crash.   
I've found the following solution:
Disable the build-before-launch.

· Select "Window->Preferences".

· In the tree view pane, expand the "Run/Debug" node, and select "Launching".

· Disable (uncheck) the "Build (if required) before launching" option in the "General Options" section, and then click "OK".
But not sure if it ok.

Comment: @ClaudiuC what version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: @ClaudiuC Interesting. I have included that workaround in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Eclipse Juno. The same version my team is using.

Answer (score 1):

Your auto build is taking long time may be you have a large workspace so If auto-build is taking too long and is interfering with ongoing development, it can be turned off. Uncheck your Build Automatically option in Project-> Build Automatically.

As shown in below image[image: build]

You can check the purpose of build automatically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677127/purpose-of-the-build-automatically-option-in-eclipse). If you need any further help you can [go here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_autobuild.htm).