# How to compile and run individual jsp file in eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I am working on web application project and it have many jsp files.
If I do any modification on particular jsp file, I need to give whole build and I have to check the appropriate changes in that JSP file. { I have tried to run jsp on server it shows like resources are missing.}

Please let me know is there any way to compile and run individual jsp file in eclipse project which can show the changes instantly without whole build project.

Comment: I guess by building whole project you mean you create a war file and deploy ? if yes you can add Server in eclipse and the changes should get deployed automatically

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Right click on the specific jsp file and click run on server. But make sure there is no dependencies from previous file.

Answer (score 0):

As you say JSP files run on the server , so they need a server to run .
They can't be run individually from the application since they might have a application flow (i.e. dependencies with previous files).

You might try using the browser tools like **Firebug** to make UI changes in your pages,

- Make note of the changes
- Fix it as a whole

Then **Clean and build** .

Another option to enable build automatically . see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677127/purpose-of-the-build-automatically-option-in-eclipse)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the response, Server is already added but individual jsp are notable to run on server from whole project, as san krish told can check changes using firebug that's what i have been using for existing jsp's. if i created new jsp file i can't able to check individually only in whole build i can check right. I am seeking alternate for this.

Comment: i guess you have no option when you deploy your code in server as `war` file . you can import your code locally and make changes that would be effective

Answer (score 0):

you just goto use this link and see the image wise jsp run:

[click 1](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/2/JSP-Hello-World-Program-using-Eclipse-IDE-and-Tomcat-web-server)

[click 2](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html)

[click 3](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/~bn0/jsp_eclipse_tutorial/)

Note: its all of the to same one in different website.

Another one sample:

```
1.Right click>Run as>Run on server>choose an exiting server>next>add(your project)>finish.
```

---

```
2.Right click>Run as>Run on server>finish.
```