# how to run java web application in eclipse with current modification in file

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications

I am doing  java dynamic web application in eclipse kepler.I am using Apache Tomcat7 as server.

I run the web application in initial with some static html page, further i changed with dynamic code an java servlet.

Now when ever I run the application it displays previous code result only.There is no change in web application what I made in file.

Please help me.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try Clean and build before you run .
2. If u want build automatically , then you should enable Build automatically (**To enable this [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677127/purpose-of-the-build-automatically-option-in-eclipse)**)
3. If the output is same after this try restarting your server .

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. It works for first time....again I have same problem when i changed content and try to run...

Comment: Yes it will work . Refresh your browser and then try

Answer (score 0):

1.check the Build Automatically in Project option in Eclipse Menu.

2.Then select the Automatically publish when resources change in the Tomcat screen(you will get it by double clicking on tomcat server in your eclipse servers tab.

[image]

I think this will help you.