# When is .class file created in JDK like eclipse?

Tags: java

Can anyone tell what happens in case of JDK's while we write code and save the file to run the application. Where and when will the .class file for my code get generated?

Comment: It's called "compilation"

Comment: See [About the Java Technology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/definition.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials. This explains what source files and class files are and how they are used.

Comment: Eclipse is not a JDK. It's IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click "run" or "build" in eclipse, the compiler will generate the `.class` files which contain your compiled code. They will be in the `/bin/` folder of your project.

Comment: But in eclipse the compilation happens in synch when we write the codes so will the .class file be generated then itself? or does it require us to build it first?

Comment: @abhilash, No, Eclipse does [not compile as you type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7677183/4428462), although you can set it it to automatically build on save. In that case, `.class` file will be generated on save.

Comment: thanks..its clear now

Answer (score 4):

Inside your *project*, a *bin* folder will be created and inside the *bin* folder, you will have your `.class` files. `class` files will be created when your code is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

When you will **compile** your code the `.class` will be created in the `bin` folder.

**On a side note:** Eclipse is automatically compiling your code and this option can be disabed by un-checking the build automatically in Project menu

Comment: What is new in this. This is already told by @TheLostMind.

Comment: @OO7:- When I started writing I didnt see that it has been answered, Thanks!